# Why can't @Value be resolved in this dependency module?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot project where project structure looks like below

```
example(artifactId = example)
 +- demo(artifactId = demo)
 |    +- src
 |    |   +-main
 |    |      +-java
 |    |        +-com
 |    |           +-example
 |    |               +-DemoService
 |    |      +-resources
 |    |          +-application.properties
 |    +- pom.xml
 +- demo2(artifactId = demo2)
 |    +- src
 |    |   +-main
 |    |      +-java
 |    |      +-resources
 |    |          +-application.properties
 |    +- pom.xml
 +-pom.xml
```

In this project "demo2" is the dependency of "demo". The "example" module is the parent of both demo and demo2. The

The problem is that when I set the property(site.password=password) in application.properties of demo, I can't resolve it in demo module like this

```
@Service
public class DemoService {

    @Value("${site.password}")
    private String password;
}
```

But if I set it to the application.properties in demo2, it can be solved in the DemoService in demo module.

Thanks in advance!

To clarify:
Demo2 is the main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same classpath resource (`classpath:application.properties`) on both jars, only one will be visible. Usually, configuration should not be packaged in a jar. It should be specified in the package with `main` method (`demo2` in your case).

You can also specify some default values for `@Value` annotations like: `@Value("${site.password:mypassword}")` [Details](http://www.mkyong.com/spring3/spring-value-default-value/)

If you still want to include properties in a jar, try putting it in a unique directory like: `src/main/resources/com/example/demo.properties` and include it in `demo2` via `spring.config.location`.

Comment: Thanks bekce. I agree that configuration should not be packaged in a jar. In my project, I have a module ("demo") that handles the stuff with mysql and redis and others modules("demo2","demo3"...) just get data from it. I set properties in "demo" because I don't want to copy the mysql/redis properties to all other modules. Is there a better way to organize the project? For example, separate the projects to several small projects. Each module is a project. "demo2" and others get data from "demo“ via RPC.

Comment: @Max You seem to be confused about module management. There are two general options for your case. 1. Each module runs by itself and provides services via REST API, RPC, or MQ. There are many `main` methods, each module has its own configuration. This is also called microservice architecture. 2. There is one `main` module and it calls methods of dependent modules (this is not RPC). There should be one configuration. Your case fits 2nd one. Generally N running instances mean N configuration, so put all conf in one module. If `demo3` will call `demo`'s method, simply `@Autowire` relevant beans.

Answer (score 0):

Application properties packaged inside your jar takes precedence, more details can be found there [https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

But you can also set which properties file to use like this

```
  --spring.config.location=classpath:/mydefault.properties
```

Comment: Thanks. Demo2 and Demo have their own property files. What I'd like to do is to make them load their own properties. Will the command "--spring.config.location=classpath:/mydefault.properties" make them load the same one?

Comment: you can give properties files  like this   --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties,classpath:/override.properties